# Can Base64String Contain Special character?

Tags: base64

I know that a Base64 string can contain `+` and `/` , but can it contain other special characters such as `$`, `|`, `'`, `*` ?

I am using this format as:

```
byte[] Data = File.ReadAllByte(Path);
String StringData = Convert.ToBase64String(Data);
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64. Search for "The Base64 index table" on the page.

Comment: Side note, but ReadAllByes() will work better.

Comment: The whole purpose of Base64 is to project into a limited char set. You know that 64+1 char set, so the answer in No.

Answer (score 3):

No, if you ask about the result of the base64 encoding.

you can search on wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: The input need not be a string and can indeed contain anything. But that was not the question.

Comment: I asked about the base64 Result

Comment: I don't know why this was not voted as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 has 64 characters
A-Z - 26 - uppercase alphabets
a-z - 26 - lowercase alphabets
0-9 - 10 - numbers
2 special characters are (+ and /)